# C# MassTransit - Consuming messages after creates new queue in runtime app throws System.ObjectDisposedException exception

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

i tried to consume new messages after creates new queue in application runtime. Follow this step-by-step example

1. Service publish new `ItemCreatedMessage` when new item is created in my app
2. The `ItemCreatedMessage` is consumed by `CreateItemQueuesConsumer` consumer

   2.1. In `CreateItemQueuesConsumer`, i configure `ConnectReceiveEndpoint` to set my queue name and use the second param `IReceiveEndpointConfigurator` to connect a consumer with a consumer factory method
3. My queues is successfuly created, binding to my exchange, and i can see they in RabbitMQ console
4. But when i publish new message to my queue, that was to be consumed by my configured consumer in factory method, the consumers throws a `System.ObjectDisposedException`

This is my following code:

```
// CreateMachineQueuesConsumer.cs

public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<MachineCreatedMessage> context)
    {
        var message = context.Message;
        var machineId = message.MachineId;
        var cancellationToken = context.CancellationToken;

        using var provider = this.serviceProvider.CreateScope();

        var createMachineStatusQueue = this.bus.ConnectReceiveEndpoint(
            string.Format("update_machine_status__{0}", machineId),
            x =>
            {
                if (x is IRabbitMqReceiveEndpointConfigurator c)
                {
                    c.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false;
                    c.ConcurrentMessageLimit = 1;
                    c.PrefetchCount = 1;

                    c.Consumer(() =>
                    {
                        return provider.ServiceProvider
                            .GetRequiredService<UpdateMachineStatusConsumer>();
                    });

                    c.Bind("machine_status_cycle", s =>
                    {
                        s.RoutingKey = machineId.ToString();
                        s.ExchangeType = ExchangeType.Direct;
                    });
                }
            });

            var anotherQueues = ...
```

When I reload my application, the messages are consumed because I have a background service that creates new queues when my application is building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect receive endpoints, you should be using `IReceiveEndpointConnector` in your consumer.

```cs
public class ThisConsumer :
    IConsumer<MachineCreatedMessage>
{
    public ThisConsumer(IReceiveEndpointConnector connector)
    {
        _connector = connector;
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<MachineCreatedMessage> context)
    {
        var message = context.Message;
        var machineId = message.MachineId;
        var cancellationToken = context.CancellationToken;

        var queueHandle = _connector.ConnectReceiveEndpoint(string.Format("update_machine_status__{0}", machineId), 
            (context, cfg) =>
            {
                cfg.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false;
                cfg.ConcurrentMessageLimit = 1;
                cfg.PrefetchCount = 1;

                cfg.ConfigureConsumer<UpdateMachineStatusConsumer(context);

                if (cfg is IRabbitMqReceiveEndpointConfigurator c)
                {
                    c.Bind("machine_status_cycle", s =>
                    {
                        s.RoutingKey = machineId.ToString();
                        s.ExchangeType = ExchangeType.Direct;
                    });
                }
            });

        // optional, don't have to wait
        await queueHandle.Ready;
    }
}
```

Also, within `AddMassTransit` make sure that you call both:

`x.AddConsumer<ThisConsumer>();`
and
`x.AddConsumer<UpdateMachineStatusConsumer>();`

This is covered [in the documentation](https://masstransit.io/documentation/configuration#receive-endpoints).

Comment: Thank you, Chris. This works fine.
But I'm still confused about the problem 

Answer (score 0):

If I had to take a guess from the code you have provided, the suspect would be code like this:

```
               c.Consumer(() =>
                {
                    return provider.ServiceProvider
                        .GetRequiredService<UpdateMachineStatusConsumer>();
                });
```

inside the scope of a lambda `x =>`  which is in turn referencing a disposable variable outside of the scope of either. Try moving the "provider" service locator inside the scope that is accessing it:

```
        x =>
        {
            if (x is IRabbitMqReceiveEndpointConfigurator c)
            {
                using var provider = this.serviceProvider.CreateScope(); // <- scoped within when this code is actually executed.
                c.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false;
                c.ConcurrentMessageLimit = 1;
                c.PrefetchCount = 1;

                c.Consumer(() =>
                {
                    return provider.ServiceProvider
                        .GetRequiredService<UpdateMachineStatusConsumer>();
                });

                c.Bind("machine_status_cycle", s =>
                {
                    s.RoutingKey = machineId.ToString();
                    s.ExchangeType = ExchangeType.Direct;
                });
            }
        });
```